# SVG feDiffuseLighting in Chrome vs Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, next.js, svg-filters

Greeting.
I faced wierd problem
I've got next.js project (default config) with svg filter

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <filter id='roughpaper'>
        <feTurbulence type="fractalNoise" baseFrequency='0.02' result='noise' numOctaves="5" />
        <feDiffuseLighting in='noise' lighting-color='white' surfaceScale='2'>
            <feDistantLight azimuth='45' elevation='60' />
        </feDiffuseLighting>
    </filter>
</svg>
```

and import like this

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

export const Paper = styled.img`
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  filter: url('/filters/paper.svg#roughpaper');
  opacity: 0.5;
`;
```

Reference [here](https://codepen.io/kekkorider/pen/xBEZyj)
And it works properly for me in Chrome and Firefox (looks like white paper)

But in next project there is a big differences.
For Firefox it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rsqdc.png)

And for Chrome like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56lhM.png)

Does any body know, why could it be?

I've already tried to set color-interpolation-filters="sRGB", but it changes nothing.

Comment: This looks 100% correct. Maybe check that your live project  has the exact same filter?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've tested different solutions. And the only thing that works properly is just put this svg inside html code of the page and do not import it from outside. Looks like there is some issue with next.js and it should be imported in some other way. Didn't found proper one yet.

Comment: One possibility - are you serving the filter from the same domain as the content? Filter content security doesn't allow cross-domain filter application for certain primitives - and Chrome may be disallowing the lighting primitive (correctly I think) whereas Firefox may be allowing it.

Comment: Yes, even on localhost